# OnAuthenticationCompleted in ASP.NET 5 RC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have an ASP.NET 5 beta 8 application which integrates with Azure Active Directory using OpenIdConnect. I tried updating the application to RC1 and changed the openid nuget package to `"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-rc1-final"`. Everything seems to be correct, but the `OnAuthenticationComplete` method which I used to add roles to my `ClaimsIdentity` is no longer in the `Events` object, and I can't find the alternative. How can I add claims to my Identity with the new version?

**UPDATE:** Changing to `OnAuthenticationValidated` still not works for me. I must be doing something wrong in my event's code:

```
OnAuthenticationValidated = async notification =>
{
    var claimsIdentity = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var userRepository=new UserRepository(Configuration);
    var userId = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
    var user = await userRepository.FindAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        await userRepository.AddAsync(new UserDto
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Username = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value,
            DisplayName = claimsIdentity?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value
        });
    }
    claimsIdentity?.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "super"));
}
```

Also, the code I use to do the login is:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login()
{
    if (HttpContext.User == null || !HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        return new ChallengeResult(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `AuthenticationCompleted` event has been renamed to `AuthenticationValidated`.

You can find more information on this ticket: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/442.

Comment: This was my first thought, but it's not working. I must be doing something wrong. I'll update the question with my event code.

Comment: "not working" is a bit vague. Is the event triggered? Have you tried to enable tracing (at the verbose level) to determine what's going on internally?

Comment: The event is not triggered. I goes to the login page but it comes back without calling the Event. I tried rolling back to beta 8 and it works. On updating to RC1 I only change the name of the event and remove `options.DefaultToCurrentUriOnRedirect = true;` because the property does not exists and it does not work anymore.

Comment: Interesting. Does it work if you use the `TicketReceived` event instead of `AuthenticationValidated`?

Comment: No, it does not get called. I think I'll start this part again from scratch (there's not much so it might be better than changing things blindly...). Thanks for your help.